# Velocity of a curve meaning

Tags: vectors, smooth-manifolds, tangent-line

[image]

This is from p.69 of John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Maniflds. Here $J$ is just an interval of $\mathbb{R}$. I am quite suspicious that this definition agrees with the usual of definition of velocity for curves whose codomains are Euclidean spaces, but entirely certain. For example. for a curve $f(t)=(t,0)$, Am I justified to write $f'(t)$ whose definition is given above just as $(1,0)$?
I am very curious.

Comment: But in this specific case, your velocity vector is constant, so at any $t_0$ you have $f'(t_0)=(1,0)$ and, as usual, you just make the cannonical identification of $T_{f(t_0)}\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: For curves like $f(t)=(t^2,0)$, then can I write like $f'(t)=(2t,0)$?

Comment: Yes, of course, why not?!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are.

As you can see in the later part of the chapter, if you a mapping F from $M\rightarrow N$ then to compute the differential $DF_p$ you just compute the Jacobian of the represantation $[D(ψ^-1Fφ)_p]$ where $ψ,φ$ ar charts in $M,N$ repsectively.

Now, in your case, you have a mapping $f$ from $\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  and therefore we can  take $ψ=φ=id$ therefore $[D(ψ^{-1}fφ)_p]=[Df_p]$.

One good thing to do when first studing smooth manifold theory is to always check if the new definitions **don't** change what we already now from usual vector calculus.

P.S. Yes for curves $f(t)=(f_1(t),...,f_n(t))$ from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $ we have that $f'(t)=(f'_1(t),...,f'_n(t))$. Note that what we are saying is just a special case of the general case of the Jacobian matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is correct.

Let $U \subset \mathbb R^2$, and ${\bf X} : U \to \mathbb R^3$.

Let $I \subset \mathbb R$, and $\gamma : I \to U$.

The composite ${\bf X} \circ \gamma$ is given by $({\bf X} \circ \gamma) \ : \ I \stackrel{\gamma}{\longrightarrow} U
\stackrel{{\bf X}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb R^3$.

For any $t \in I$, we get $(u(t),v(t)) \in U$ and then $\alpha(t):=({\bf X} \circ \gamma)(t) = {\bf X}(u(t),v(t)) \in \mathbb R^3$.

Using the Chain Rule gives $\dot{\alpha}(t)=\dot u{\bf X}_u +\dot v{\bf X}_v$.

This is a vector in $\mathbb R^3$, based at ${\bf X}(u(t),v(t))$ and tangent to ${\bf X}(U)$.

As an example:

Let ${\bf X}(u,v) = (u,v,u^2-v^2)$ and $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$.
In this case $U=\mathbb R^2$ and $I = [0,2\pi)$.

$({\bf X} \circ \gamma)(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, \cos^2t - \sin^2t)$.

Simplifying gives $({\bf X} \circ \gamma)(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, \cos 2t)$.

Hence $\dot \alpha(t) = (-\sin t, \cos t, -2\sin 2t)$.